# How to remove an object from List<T> in C# and return the removed object?

Tags: c#, .net, list

How to remove an object from `List<T>` in C# and return the removed object ?

Does `RemoveAt` destroys the object?
Do I need to first make deep copy of the object and then call `RemoveAt`?

Comment: RemoveAt does not destroy the object and a deep copy will not be needed.

Comment: RemoveAt will not destroy the object! You could store the object in a temp var, do something like this: var obj = list[index]; list.RemoveAt[index]; This in only needed when u need the object else the garbage collector will destroy it

Comment: In .NET, there is **no way** to explicitly destroy an object; that concept *does not exist*. Either an object is reachable via the references, or it is not. In the latter case, the garbage collector will destroy it *at some indeterminate point*

Comment: If you remove the assertion that the object is destroyed, is this question a duplicate?

Comment: Edited, changed the statements of fact to questions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

RemoveAt does not destroy the object and a deep copy will not be needed.

```
var result = list[i];
list.RemoveAt(i);
return result;
```

[`RemoveAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z.aspx) is O(*n* - *i*) vs [`Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e.aspx) which is O(*n*) (where *n* is the length and *i* is the index of the element to be removed). After you've removed an element, you have to shift everything after it down one.

According to this documentation, if you want the most performant way of removing an element, swap it with last, element and then remove that. This does not maintain the order like the above. In theory this means that it is O(1) to remove the last element of a list.

```
var result = list[i];
list[i] = list[list.Length-1];
list.RemoveAt(list.Length-1);
return result;
```

Comment: This is (a tiny bit) better than the other answer. (1) Using the indexer notation `[i]` is more concise and direct than going through the general Linq extension method `.ElementAt(i)`. (2) `RemoveAt(i)` is much faster than `Remove(valueInList)` because it won't have to search through the `List<>` to find a match to remove.

Answer (score 7):

You could do:

```
var listObject = list.ElementAt(index);

list.Remove(listObject);
```

Comment: But does not that destroy the object?

Comment: @user2381422 why would that destroy the object? all we are pulling from the list is a *reference* - which is then assigned to `listObject`

Comment: No, just removes its reference from the list. Because `listObject` is also a reference to that object, it doesn't become eligible for garbage collection (which is the only way it could be "destroyed").

Comment: Commenters: Of course, you are assuming in your comments that `T` is a reference type in this case (values of a value type are also sometimes refered to as "objects" even if they are not boxed).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Even in this case a copy will be made, so the net effect is the same - you still can return a usable object that matched what you just "deleted" from the list. But, still a good point, and yes an assumption on our part.

Answer (score -3):

I am so sorry i misundersand the question.

this is my answer,you should use function.

```
public xxxx sss(List s,var i)
{
  try
{
var result = s.ElementAt(i);
s.Remove(result);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
Console.WriteLine(e.message);
}
}
```

Comment: Downvoted. A new class with a destructor is not helpful for this topic.

Comment: so sorry i misundersanded.